# Stop-Service -ComputerName parameter ignored through SQL Agent

Tags: sql, powershell, sql-agent

I have the following code which sucessfully stops a service on remote computer when run from the powershell console.

```
$Computer = "192.168.24.23"
$service = "Credential Checking LIVE"
Get-Service -ComputerName $Computer -name $service | Stop-Service
```

When i run this through a SQL Agent job the -ComputerName parameter is ignored.

Any ideas on why this would be and what i can do to rectify the problem?

Comment: FYI this is not a bat file but a powershell script. It should run in the powerhsell console, not in cmd.

Comment: What user does the SQL server agent run as? Is it possible that it doesn't have permission to connect to the remote computer?

Answer (score 0):

I'd check the following
1) Does the SQL agent have rights to execute? (like briantist said)
2) Have you tried putting the logic in a script and executing the script from SQL?
3) Did you forget that you had to enter Set-Execution policy while testing?